# Best way to draw algorithm on the board

Tags: algorithm, drawing, representation

Sorry for my uncleared question - i search best way to draw some algorithm on the board and clarify him for myself
but few hours i waste to try do all in my head - and think it was not efficient at all . . .

what do you can recommend ?

Comment: It really depends on the algorithm...

Comment: @Patronus Absurd without extra detail, you know the Q is unclear

Comment: If it's a whiteboard, I recommend using non-permanent marker pens.  For blackboards, you should use only chalk.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [Flowcharts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart), it is all you need :). For example this is example of computing factorial : [image]

Comment: +1 for intuition.  After seeing your answer, I can almost imagine that is what the OP was trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The most common notation to represent algorithms is flow charts.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart

UML Activity Diagrams are also common when designing software algorithms:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram

There are many tools out there that will help you out drawing them. I tend to use www.cacoo.com.